# Converting the Alpha in RGBA to CSS Opacity

Tags: php, css, image

I am trying to get the transparency from RGBA and convert it to CSS opacity.

So after getting the RGBA of an image pixel using the following:

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($img, $j, $i);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);
// Printing colors, I get
// 255,255,255,127
// 249,161,66,126
//...
```

For some reason, the transparency is always an integer (i.e. 127) and not a decimal number. But I want to convert that 127 figure to something I can use in CSS:

```
opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)
```

However, I can't work out the link between alpha in RGBA and how I can turn it into CSS opacity.

I will be doing this for all sorts of pixels from different types of images. PNG, JPG, GIF

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opacity = (127 - transparency) / 127.0`

Comment: This _only_ works because the GD functions are broken and are losing one bit of resolution (i.e. using 0..127 instead of 0..255)

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is the opposite of transparency.

Given a transparency range of 0 .. 255:

```
opacity = (255 - transparency) / 255.0
```

If your max value is different just replace both occurrences of 255 with that value.

Comment: this will only give you half transparency since the transparency value in rgba format has a max value of 127

Comment: @slash197 is right, I tested it and it gives half transparency. Anyway to account for this?

Comment: `opacity = (127 - transparency) / 127.0`

Comment: @slash197 in what system is your max value 127?  In _every_ RGBA system I've used the transparency goes to 255.

Comment: @slash197 Feel free to add that as an answer, because it works! Just to add, will this work for all types of images? A naive question but I am getting everything pixel by pixel so image type shouldn't break this formula?

Comment: @slash197 ah - PHP/GD fail.  In a proper 32-bit RGBA space the alpha _should_ be between 0 and 255.

Comment: @Alnitak I know, it's pretty weird